# Why a ts-class-based vue-component's static method, which is declared in .vue, can only work in a .vue's script block?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

Why a ts-class-based vue-component's static method, which is declared in .vue, can only work in a .vue's script block?

### steps to reproduce

1. use vue-cli3 to init a typescript project and add shims-vue.d.ts

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

2. add **Comp.vue** file in your project as below

```
// Comp.vue 
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class Comp extends Vue {
  mounted() {

  }
  created(){

  }
  static notWorkFunc(){
    //anything
  }
}

export function anotherNotWorkFunc(){
  //anything
}
</script>
```

3. add **test.ts** and **test.vue** in your project with specific code as below

**test.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import ComP,{anotherNotWorkFun} from "./Comp.vue";
ComP.notWorkFunc()
anotherNotWorkFun()
</script>
```

[image]

**test.ts**

```
import ComP,{anotherNotWorkFun} from "./Comp.vue";
ComP.notWorkFunc()
anotherNotWorkFun()
```

[image]

As you can see

in **.ts** not work

in **.vue** work

I don't know the reason...

The repo is https://github.com/WilkinWendy/vue-ts-problem.

The democode is in ./src/demo

FYI

Answer (score 1):

I think the typescript class components in `.vue` files actually get compiled to a Vue options object and that is how they are exported.
What we do in our project, is in the `.vue` file we just have the template and at the bottom we have external reference to a code-behind file.
Example:

```html
<!-- Comp.vue -->
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" src="./Comp.ts"></script>
<style lang="scss" src="./Comp.scss"></style>
```

Then we do the following:

```js
// Comp.ts
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

export const SOME_CONST = "SomeValue";

@Component
export class Comp extends Vue{
  public static method(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

export default Comp;
```

this seems to work for us and actually the performance of VSCode/Vetur/TypeScript is much better this way. In addition, when the UX folks work on the CSS/HTML they don't have to touch the `.ts` file.

Comment: ehhh....,maybe you havn't  understand my problem, my question is Comp.vue is fixed,
when i import Comp.vue in test.vue,it's ok.
when i import Comp.vue in test.ts,it errors.

Comment: you can just download my repo to see

Comment: No, I got it all right, we have the same issue. The solution I suggested allows you to import the code in .vue .js and .ts files. Give it a try

Comment: I have tried as you said. it works when i 
correct 
**import ComP,{anotherNotWorkFun} from "./Comp.vue";**
to
**import ComP,{anotherNotWorkFun} from "./Comp";**

Comment: but why this happen,

why  **import ComP,{anotherNotWorkFun} from "./Comp.vue";** can no longer be recognized in .vue, even if it works before

Comment: A .vue file gets compiled into 3 separate files, you'll see it in the browser dev tools if you search for the file name. There may be a way to make the compiler to reroute the file name. But I don't know what that is. Also, in a .vue file, as mentioned. The class gets converted to a vue option object and is not used exactly as is so there's some abstraction going on in the background

Comment: yes,i know what you describe, maybe this lint error is just a typescript typecheck bug

Comment: I am curious about why in **.vue** script block, everything is ok,what controls this.